# Where can I find Seido resources?

Tags: karate, forms

I am an advanced blue belt in the Seido Karate system, and it has been very difficult to find any resources pertaining to katas and kumite. I would love to have a video or written instructions for these aspects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seido is related to kyokushin so a lot of the kara are very similar.  When it comes to the kihon kumite you may be out of luck.  You may want to write and/or film yourself doing your new material as a reference for later

Answer (score 3):

As Seido Karate System is close to kyokushin system you could search the internet for the kyokushin katas and ask your instructor for the differencies between them. Also you could contact http://www.seido.com for more info.